# Memory Leak when sending image as an attachment via Email

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a camera application where the user can share the photos taken through email.
I am using MFMailComposerViewController to send mail. Here is the piece of code.

```
- (void) contactEmailRecepients:(NSArray *)emailIDs
                    subject:(NSString *)subject
                 attachment:(NSMutableDictionary *)attachmentDictionary
                     sender:(UIViewController *)sender
{   

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailViewController setToRecipients:emailIDs];
    [mailViewController setSubject:subject];

    NSData *attachmentData = [attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"attachmentData"];
    if (nil != attachmentData)
    {
        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:attachmentData
                                     mimeType:[attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"mimeType"]
                                     fileName:[attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"]];
    }

    [sender presentViewController:mailViewController
                         animated:YES
                       completion:^{}];

    attachmentData = nil;
    [attachmentDictionary removeAllObjects];
    attachmentDictionary = nil;
}
else
{
// display error message
}
}
```

My problem is every time I send a mail through my application the VM(Virtual Memory) increases by 6/7 MB. But this does not happen if I comment out following part.

```
  if (nil != attachmentData)
    {
        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:attachmentData
                                     mimeType:[attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"mimeType"]
                                     fileName:[attachmentDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"]];
    }
```

The increased VM is due to `CGRasterData`and the responsible library is `CoreGraphics`and responsible caller is `CGDataProvideCreateWithCopyOfData`when I check it through Xcode 5.0.2 instruments.So somewhere a copy is getting created which is not getting released later.I am suspecting the memory allocated to display the image in Email `UIActionSheet`is not getting released.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Adding the piece of code where `attachmentData` is getting initialized.

```
- (void)postPhotoFromPath:(NSString *)filePath
               sender:(UIViewController *)sender
{

 NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

if (nil == photoData)
{
 //display error message
}
else
{
    NSString *fileName = [[filePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
    [self contactEmailRecepients:nil
                         subject:nil
                      attachment:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  photoData, @"attachmentData",
                                  @"image/jpeg", @"mimeType",
                                  fileName, @"fileName",
                                  nil]
                          sender:sender];
}
}
```

Also I noticed carefully that VM increases exactly when i get the `UIActionSheet`regarding which image size to send(whether to send the original size or downscaled size). I am attaching the screenshot for the same here.
[image: UIActionSheet for selecting the image size to be sent]

Comment: can you post the code related to attachmentData allocation before adding to your attachmentDictionary?

Comment: Chancy, I have updated my question regarding attachmentData allocation.

Comment: I have noticed the same memory increase when sending just a normal email with no attachments. It seems to jump up by 2mb when the action sheet is displayed (e.g. the user presses cancel and then Delete Draft)